# What does the "%du" format specifier mean for scanf?

Tags: c, assembly, scanf, reverse-engineering

I have disassembled a program (in IDA), and stumbled upon this block of code:

```
lea     ecx, [ebp+Str1]
push    ecx             ; char
push    offset aDu      ; " %du"
call    scanf
add     esp, 8
cmp     eax, 1
```

I've tried searching up what `%du` means, without success. I know `%d` means decimal integer and `%u` means an unsigned int.

Does it mean `%du` is an unsigned int? if so, why do we need the `d` anyways?

Just asking to be sure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the documentation for `scanf()` say?

Comment: There's no "du" format specifier. It's `%d` followed by literal `u`. e.g. `5u`.

Comment: There's no such standard format specifier for `scanf`. It means a decimal integer number followed by the literal letter `u`.

Answer (score 3):

`%du` isn't a valid conversion specifier. This is simply a `%d` followed by printing the letter `u`, as if the programmer intended to `u` suffix their input/output like `123u`.

Comment: Does it still do the `%d` conversion if there's no trailing `u`?  I think so, because scanf iterates one character / conversion at a time up to the first mismatch IIRC. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf  So it's just `%d` and then optionally consuming a trailing `u` if there is one.  The caller doesn't find out whether there was one or not (return value = number of conversions), so it's not usable for something like a C compiler where `1u` and `1` have different meanings.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah it does reading everything up to that point. From 7.21.6.2 "A directive that is an ordinary multibyte character is executed by reading the next characters of the
stream. If any of those characters differ from the ones composing the directive,the directive fails and the differing and subsequent characters remain unread. Similarly, if end-of-file, an encoding error, or a read error prevents a character from being read, the directive fails."  Meaning that `scanf("%du%d",&x,&y);` will read x but will only read y if there's a `u` in the input.

Comment: Right, so I think that's an important point to mention, that this *can* parse a number out of inputs that don't end in `u`, consuming a trailing `u` is optional and happens after a normal `%d` conversion.  We can't infer that inputs to this scanf always end with `u`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Though if I'm to speculate, maybe the programmer just intended to switch between %d and %u but slipped on the keyboard.

Comment: Side note, if it *was* intentional and failure to find a 'u' should be reported, a simple trick is to change the format to ```scanf("%du%n", &i, &n)``` and check the return value of scanf. If no 'u' is found, the '%n' is left untouched and the return value is 1 (or 0 if no number gets parsed, either). Otherwise it is 2 and the int n is filled with the number of consumed characters.